# How to display all elements from a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to display all elements when the position is selected from a dropdown box when I select a position the correct elements display but when I select all to display all the elements nothing is displayed.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="players.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="playerFilter.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<h1>Players by Position</h1>
<select id="position">
<option value=''>Select...</option>
<option value='All'>All</option>
<option value='Goalkeeper'>Goalkeeper</option>
<option value='Defender'>Defender</option>
<option value='Midfielder'>Midfielder</option>
<option value='Forward'>Forward</option>
</select>
<hr>

<div id="data"></div>

</body>
```

.JS File:

```
window.onload=function()
{

    document.getElementById('position').onchange=function()
    {
        function getPlayerPosition(element)
        {
            if(element.Position == $("#position").val())
             return true;
        }

        var playerPosition = _.filter(players, getPlayerPosition);
        console.log(playerPosition);

        $("#data").html("");
        _.each(playerPosition, function(element){
            $("#data").append(element.Name + "<br>");
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you mix vanilla js , jQuery and underscore

Comment: I couldn't get it working any other way

Comment: post the other files of your project and you will have a quick response

Comment: how are you getting "players" that's being passed to  _.filter?

Answer (score 0):

Using only jquery you can do like this using [**attribute-not-equal-selector**] selector[1](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

```js
$("#position").on('change', function() {
  var str = '';
  if ($(this).val() === "All") {
    var getAllElem = $("#position option").not("[value='All']").not("[value='']").each(function(i, v) {
      str += $(v).text() + ' ';
    })
    $("#data").html(str);
  } else {
    $("#data").html($(this).val());
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Players by Position</h1>
<select id="position">
        <option value=''>Select...</option>
        <option value='All'>All</option>
        <option value='Goalkeeper'>Goalkeeper</option>
        <option value='Defender'>Defender</option>
        <option value='Midfielder'>Midfielder</option>
        <option value='Forward'>Forward</option>
    </select>
<hr>
<div id="data"></div>
```